# How to relate the sign of an integral function with the sign of the function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> *Question*: Say we have $H(x)=\int_0^x h(t)dt$ (to avoid issues we'll assume being $f$ integrable on that interval). How can we relate the sign of the function on a given interval $[a,b]$ with the integral function H?

> *Example that made me confused:* Define $h(x)=\frac{4x-1}{(x+4)(x^2+1)}$ and $H(x)=\int_0^{\frac{x}{2}} h $. Find the amount of zeros that $H$ has in the interval $[\frac{1}{2},4]$.

*What I tried/thought*: Since we know that the function is strictly increasing, we should then look at the signs at the ends of the interval:

*Doubt*. I was told that if the integrand (the function itself in this case) was positive in that interval, then the integral $H$ would be as well positive, likewise with negatives, but I don't think that's true? Let me take that example, it's clear that in the interval $[0,\frac{1}{4}]$ we know $h<0$ and that for $[\frac{1}{4},\infty)$ we have $h>0$. Took the graph of both $H$ and $h$:

[image: Graph of H and h]

Here we clearly see that was I was told isn't true, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

What you were told is true and is not contradicted by your graphs.

Since $h\ge0$ on the interval $[1/4,+\infty),$ $\int_a^bh\ge0$ for any segment $[a,b]$ *in this interval*.

In particular,
$$\forall x\ge\frac12\quad0\le\int_{1/4}^{x/2}h=H(x)-H(1/2),$$
which you can check on your picture.